# Проблема с visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такой вопрос,я в менюшке сделал,для невидимых элементов вместо dislay: none, visibility:hidden, при наведении на li менюшки вылезает еще одна с visibility:visible, вылезает быстро, а вот пропадает медленно, как это исправить?

Comment: прикрепите сниппет на котором можно воспроизвести проблему, по вашему описанию сложно понять что не так

Comment: Вот с этим как раз проблемы, код уже ооочень большой.

Comment: Так весь код и не надо, сварганьте минимальный пример на котором можно проблему воспроизвести.

Comment: Пока писал код, и ошибку,сам же исправил) там где visiblity:visible добавил opacity: 1; а, где visibility : hidden - добавил opacity:0; Наверно, это фишка visibility, на медленное реагирование.Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столкнулся с visability впервые, искал замену display:block, т.к. нужен был доступ к дочерним элементам, оказалось, может ошибаюсь, что visability работает то ли медленно, то ли анимация такая, не знаю, но при исчезании/появлении, также с visability, необходимо использовать opacity.